# PHP shell scipt for command injection

Tags: php

Hello I need a PHP SHELL script that can do a command injection on a webserever. it is for a computer science securuty challenge. I must upload the scipt on the webserever and the command should be executed. The command tha needs to be exectuted is : victory_en 686

I tried several things without succes.

I also tried this:

```
<?php
shell_exec 'victory_en 686'
?>
```

But it doesn't works.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) runs a command. So something like:

```
<?php exec("victory_en 686"); ?>
```

Comment: That picture says 702, not 686

Comment: Yes i had also made that change but no success.